# Expand existing Copy-Paste Loop: Loop through specific Columns based on Cell Value

Tags: excel, vba, loops, for-loop, copy-paste

I currently have multiple excel spreadhsheets that look like this:

[image: My Table]

The table is a questionnaire with answers from column C-F, C is the "worst" (letter N), D the "second worst" (letter T), E the second best (letter W) and F the best (letter G as in Good).

To the right of this table are sentences that I copy to another Spreadsheet using an existing module, depending on where the "x" in the questionnaire is set (it always copies the sentence 9 rows to the right of the "x").

Now I want to modify my existing code to not just copy all the sentences from every row, but only copy 5 for each Worksheet. These 5 should be either the 5 "best" answers (5 from column F, meaning Good as answer in questionnaire, if there are less than 5 in that column then take the rest from column E until you have 5) or the 6 "worst" answers, meaning 5 from column C(letter N as in not good) and if there are less than 5 "X" in that column take the rest from column D (letter T). This way I want to copy the 5 best or worst answers for each Worksheet. The decision if the best or worst answers should be copied depends on one simple Cell Value (Cell K6) in each Worksheet. If K6 >70% take the best answers, if K6 is under 70%, take the worst answers.

This is my current module to copy all the answers to my new worksheet:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lr As Integer 'lastrow
Dim SpaltenIndex As Integer
Dim SheetNummer As Integer
Dim cl As Range 'cell
Dim rw As Range 'row
Dim Antwortrange As String
Dim WrkSht As Worksheet
Dim WrkShtCol As Sheets


'Create Destination Sheet
Sheets.Add
ActiveSheet.Name = "Handlungsempfehlungen"

'Set Questionnaire Answer Range to search through
Antwortrange = "C11:F400"

'ColumnIndex and SheetNumber
SpaltenIndex = 1
SheetNummer = 1

'Create Worksheet Collection with all the Questionnaire-Sheets
Set WrkShtCol = Worksheets(Array("AM AD - Anforderungsdefinition", "AM AA - Anforderunganalyse", "AM - Anforderungsdokumentation", "AM AV - Anforderungsvalidierung", "TM IT - Initiierung Test", "TM ZD - Zieldefinition", "TM TV - Testvorgehen", "TM TOB - Testobjektabgrenzung", "TM AS - Aufwandsschätzung", "TM TP - Testplanung", "TM TP - Testplanung", "TM TA - Testauftrag", "TM TS - Teststeuerung", "TM AO - Aufbauorganisation", "TM RM - Risikomanagement", "TM MI - Managementinformation", "TM AF - Abnahme Freigabe", "TM AT - Abschluss Test", "DT IT - Installationstest", "DT ST - Sicherheitstest", "OTP DT - Dokumententest", "OTP MT - Modultest", "OTP MIT - Modulintegrationstest", "OTP OO KT - OO Klassentest", "OTP OO KIT - OO Klassenintgrate", "OTP FT - Funktionstest", "OTP FIT - Funktionsintgratiotes", "OTP PIT - Produktintegratest", "OTP AT - Abnahmetest", "OTP ET - Ergonomietest", "OTP LPT - Last & Performance", "OTP GPT - Geschäftsprozesstest", "TUP TMK -Testumg Module Klassen", _
"TUP TUF - Testumgebung Funktion", "TUP TP - Testumgebung Prozesse", "ATP KM Konfigurationsmanagement", "ATP FAEM - Fehler Änderungs", "ATP DS - Datensicherheit", "ATP DSCH - Datenschutz", "ATP TEV -Testergebnisverwaltung", "ATP VG - Vertragsgestaltung"))
   
'MAIN LOOP: Take all sentences 9 rows to the right of each X in each Questionnaire and paste the value to the newly created sheet from above

For Each WrkSht In WrkShtCol

   For Each rw In WrkSht.Range(Antwortrange).Rows   
   For Each cl In rw.Cells
       
   lr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, SpaltenIndex).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
   If lr = 2 And ws.Range("A1") = "" And lr < 500 Then lr = 1
   'If lr = 2 And ws.Range("A2") = "" Then lr = 1
      
           If LCase(cl.Value) = "x" Then
               cl.Offset(0, 9).Copy Sheets("Handlungsempfehlungen").Cells(lr, SpaltenIndex)       
           End If
       Next cl
   Next rw



'If 1st row is empty in destination sheet, delete and shift rest up 
If Sheets("Handlungsempfehlungen").Cells(1, SpaltenIndex) = "" Then Sheets("Handlungsempfehlungen").Cells(1, SpaltenIndex).Delete Shift:=xlUp

'WrkShtCol(1).range("A2").Copy Worksheets("Handlungsempfehlungen").Cell(lr, SpaltenIndex)

Sheets("Handlungsempfehlungen").Cells(35, SpaltenIndex).Value = WrkShtCol(SheetNummer).Cells(2, 1)


SpaltenIndex = SpaltenIndex + 1
SheetNummer = SheetNummer + 1


End Sub
```

I hope you can help me, any tips would be greatly appreciated. Thank you so much in advance.

Edit - Expected Results:

If K6 is over 70% - find the 5 best answers (1st priority column F, if there are 5 "x" in column F, find those Cells and copy the value 9 rows to the right to the new sheet.

So if the questionnaire looks like this: [QuestionnaireOver70%](https://gyazo.com/68b0a0bd839acdc0626fb8ddda6a7060)
The pasted table should look like this: [Table](https://gyazo.com/12179a45524816ae49f423d647088642)

And if the questionnaire is under 70%, do the same but for the worst (Column C & D, C being the worst, if there are not 5 "x" in C then take the rest from D (second worst))

Hope this helps

EDIT: the File with all the sheets I want to copy from and the current module:
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/wq8dgzmlpxgm76x/AACOG_SkE9WMqE22qvcd3tVBa?dl=0

EDIT: Updated link, excel file has more explanation with needed steps and worksheets to help understand (One with current output, one with desired output)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post a sample of the expected results

Comment: Done that, including Screenshots, hope it helps :)

Comment: It's better if you include rows and columns headers in your screenshot

Comment: Youre right. I fixed it.

Comment: also added a dropbox link to the file with the macro in it and all the sheet :)

Comment: I've looked at the file and your instructions but I'm not able to follow them. If you can break them in steps like: step 1) add a new sheet 2) Select cell K6 3) Check if the value is > 70% 4) If it is, Select range XXXX 5) Copy values from column A where cells in that range are marked with an X ... etc...

Comment: I edited the file and wrote the steps in it & made 2 Extra Worksheets with the old result and how the new one should look like, this should help to understand :) 
Heres the new link: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/wq8dgzmlpxgm76x/AACOG_SkE9WMqE22qvcd3tVBa?dl=0
Thank you so much for your help Ricardo

Comment: In the "how it should be" sheed i did the "how it should be"-version for the first 3 sheets only, not all 40 as this is enough to understand the wanted pattern (or at least I hope it is)

Comment: I’ll try to take a look at it tomorrow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read code's comments and adjust it to fit your needs

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub DoSomething()

    ' Define the results sheet's name
    Dim resultsSheetName As String
    resultsSheetName = "Handlungsempfehlungen"
    
    ' Set the results sheet reference
    Dim resultsSheet As Worksheet
    Set resultsSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(resultsSheetName)

    ' Define the sheets to evaluate in an array
    Dim targetSheets As Sheets
    Set targetSheets = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Array("AM AD - Anforderungsdefinition", "AM AA - Anforderunganalyse", _
                        "AM - Anforderungsdokumentation", "AM AV - Anforderungsvalidierung", _
                        "TM IT - Initiierung Test", "TM ZD - Zieldefinition", _
                        "TM TV - Testvorgehen", "TM TOB - Testobjektabgrenzung", _
                        "TM AS - Aufwandsschätzung", "TM TP - Testplanung", _
                        "TM TP - Testplanung", "TM TA - Testauftrag", _
                        "TM TS - Teststeuerung", "TM AO - Aufbauorganisation", _
                        "TM RM - Risikomanagement", "TM MI - Managementinformation", _
                        "TM AF - Abnahme Freigabe", "TM AT - Abschluss Test", _
                        "DT IT - Installationstest", "DT ST - Sicherheitstest", _
                        "OTP DT - Dokumententest", "OTP MT - Modultest", _
                        "OTP MIT - Modulintegrationstest", "OTP OO KT - OO Klassentest", _
                        "OTP OO KIT - OO Klassenintgrate", "OTP FT - Funktionstest", _
                        "OTP FIT - Funktionsintgratiotes", "OTP PIT - Produktintegratest", _
                        "OTP AT - Abnahmetest", "OTP ET - Ergonomietest", _
                        "OTP LPT - Last & Performance", "OTP GPT - Geschäftsprozesstest", _
                        "TUP TMK -Testumg Module Klassen", "TUP TUF - Testumgebung Funktion", _
                        "TUP TP - Testumgebung Prozesse", "ATP KM Konfigurationsmanagement", _
                        "ATP FAEM - Fehler Änderungs", "ATP DS - Datensicherheit", _
                        "ATP DSCH - Datenschutz", "ATP TEV -Testergebnisverwaltung", _
                        "ATP VG - Vertragsgestaltung"))

    ' Loop through each sheet
    Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
    For Each targetSheet In targetSheets
        
        ' Get last row in target sheet
        Dim lastRow As Long
        lastRow = targetSheet.Cells(targetSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        
        'targetSheet.Activate
        
        ' Remove any filters
        If targetSheet.FilterMode Then targetSheet.ShowAllData
        
        ' Set the range with X
        Dim rangeToFilter As Range
        Set rangeToFilter = targetSheet.Range("C7:F" & lastRow)
    
        ' Define a counter to check how many X there are
        Dim resultCounter As Long
        resultCounter = 1
        
        ' Check the grade (
        Dim gradeValue As Variant
        gradeValue = targetSheet.Range("K6").Value
        
        ' Check if the grade is not an error
        If Not IsError(gradeValue) Then
            
            ' Define the columns to filter (in order) according to the grade value
            Select Case gradeValue
            Case Is > 0.7
                    
                Dim columnsToFilter As Variant
                columnsToFilter = Array(4, 3) ' Columns F and E
                
            Case Else
                
                columnsToFilter = Array(1, 2) ' Columns C and D
                
            End Select
            
            ' Set a reference to the range that holds the Xs in first column
            Dim resultRange As Range
            Set resultRange = filterRange(rangeToFilter, columnsToFilter(0), "X")
            
            ' If there are any results in first column
            If Not resultRange Is Nothing Then
                ' Count them
                Dim countResult As Long
                countResult = resultRange.Count
                
                ' Get the results sheet's last row
                Dim resultsRow As Long
                resultsRow = resultsSheet.Cells(resultsSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
                
                ' Print the results in results sheet
                printResults resultsSheet, resultsRow, resultRange, resultCounter
                
            End If

            ' If the results with Xs are less than five
            If resultCounter <= 5 Then
                ' Remove filters from sheet
                If targetSheet.FilterMode Then targetSheet.ShowAllData
                
                ' Set a reference to the range that holds the Xs in second column
                Set resultRange = filterRange(rangeToFilter, columnsToFilter(1), "X")
                
                ' If there are any results in second column
                If Not resultRange Is Nothing Then
                    
                    ' Print the results in results sheet
                    printResults resultsSheet, resultsRow, resultRange, resultCounter
                End If
            End If
            
        End If
        
    Next targetSheet

End Sub

Private Function filterRange(ByVal rangeToFilter As Range, ByVal fieldToFilter As Long, ByVal criteriaToFilter As String) As Range
    
    ' Apply auto filter in selected column
    rangeToFilter.AutoFilter Field:=fieldToFilter, Criteria1:=criteriaToFilter
    
    ' Use error handling to handle the case in which there aren't any results
    On Error Resume Next
    Set filterRange = rangeToFilter.Offset(1, 0).Columns(fieldToFilter).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function

' In this sub is used the variable resultCounter ByRef which means that the value is passed back to the variable that is in the calling procedure
Private Sub printResults(ByVal resultsSheet As Worksheet, ByVal resultsRow As Long, ByVal resultRange As Range, ByRef resultCounter As Long)
    
    Dim targetCell As Range
    For Each targetCell In resultRange
        
        If resultCounter <= 5 Then
            resultsSheet.Range("A" & resultsRow + resultCounter).Resize(1, 3).Value = Array(resultRange.Parent.Name, resultCounter, targetCell.Offset(0, 9).Value)
        Else
            Exit For
        End If
        
        resultCounter = resultCounter + 1
        
    Next targetCell
    
End Sub
```

PS. I could't understand the output in "Handlungsempfehlungen" so I left a generic one

Let me know if it works

Comment: This is beautiful and helped me so much, thank you Ricardo!

Comment: Remember to break things in steps begining with the end in mind. Then you can code anything you want